# Angular Material Autocomplete Shifting Body Up 66px

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I have added the following code to my webpage:

```
<md-content>
    <md-autocomplete md-search-text="vm.searchText"
                     md-selected-item-change="vm.selectedItemChange(item)"
                     md-item-text="item.Name"
                     md-no-cache="true"
                     md-input-minlength="3"
                     md-selected-item="vm.selectedItem"
                     md-items="item in vm.querySearch(vm.searchText)"
                     placeholder="Employee or Project">
        <md-item-template>
            <span md-highlight-text="vm.searchText" md-highlight-flags="^i" ng-class="item.Type == 1 ? 'Employee' : 'Project'">{{item.Name}}</span>
        </md-item-template>
        <md-not-found>
            No states matching "{{vm.searchText}}" were found.
        </md-not-found>
        <span flex="" md-whiteframe="-1">{{item.Name}}</span>
    </md-autocomplete>
</md-content>
```

and every time I click into the input of the autocomplete it shifts the page up by adding the following style to the <body> tag of my page (which is outside the scope of the Angular app as its applied to a subtag (a SPAN)):

`position: fixed; width: 100%; top: -66px; overflow: hidden`

How do I fix this / stop it from doing that?

Comment: Seems okay to me - http://codepen.io/camden-kid/pen/Lkmyvw?editors=1010#0

Comment: Yes, your code does work, why I don't know.  I've uploaded an archive containing a bare minimum project that replicates the problem for me.  it is at https://1drv.ms/u/s!At6M2gNuPNegq1dtc-cC4hUzozfN. If you run Test.html in the archive, you will see the issue as soon as you type any content.

Comment: Found issue.  In the code I uploaded I added "margin-top: 100px" to the div containing the ng-app.  It is this margin-top that it is trying to undo by adding top: -100px to the body.  Which is frustrating as the page I'm inserting my HTML into is not a fully material design page, and apart from this, everything else is working fine.

P.S.  Padding doesn't cause the problem, just margin.

Comment: Regardless, removing the margin and replacing it with padding solved it for me (the other option is to position: relative or absolute).

Comment: Glad you got it sorted out.